# data.table or dplyr - data manipulation

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, data-manipulation, dplyr

I have the following data

```
Date           Col1       Col2
2014-01-01     123        12
2014-01-01     123        21
2014-01-01     124        32
2014-01-01     125        32
2014-01-02     123        34
2014-01-02     126        24
2014-01-02     127        23
2014-01-03     521        21
2014-01-03     123        13
2014-01-03     126        15
```

Now, I want to count unique values in `Col1` for the each date (that did not repeat in previous date), and add to the previous count. For example,

```
Date           Count
2014-01-01       3 i.e. 123,124,125
2014-01-02       5 (2 + above 3) i.e. 126, 127
2014-01-03       6 (1 + above 5) i.e. 521 only
```

Comment: The output I am looking for is Date and Count columns shown above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %.% 
  arrange(Date) %.% 
  filter(!duplicated(Col1)) %.% 
  group_by(Date) %.% 
  summarise(Count=n()) %.% # n() <=> length(Date)
  mutate(Count = cumsum(Count))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
#         Date Count
# 1 2014-01-01     3
# 2 2014-01-02     5
# 3 2014-01-03     6

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key="Date")
dt <- unique(dt, by="Col1")
(dt <- dt[, list(Count=.N), by=Date][, Count:=cumsum(Count)])
#          Date Count
# 1: 2014-01-01     3
# 2: 2014-01-02     5
# 3: 2014-01-03     6
```

Or

```
dt <- data.table(df, key="Date")
dt <- unique(dt, by="Col1")
dt[, .N, by=Date][, Count:=cumsum(N)]
```

`.N` is named `N` (no dot) automatically for convenience in chained operations like this, so you can use both `.N` and `N` together in the next operation if need be.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I like data.table option better.

Comment: Thanks @Arun. I'm rather new to data table. But I'm starting to love it. :)

Comment: It may be more efficient (in `dplyr`)  to use `filter` to de-duplicate on `col1` , i.e. `df %.% arrange(Date) %.% filter(!duplicated(Col1)) %.% group_by(Date) %.% summarise(Count=length(Date)) %.% mutate(Count = cumsum(count))`.

Comment: I'm with @mnel - the dplyr code would look a lot better if you consistently used `%.%`

Comment: @mnel The use of `n()` instead of `length` will be probably better too. cc @hadley

Comment: @lukeA, I have another column now which is named 'Type' in that I have 'Type1', 'Type2' and 'Type3'. I want cumulative sum based on 'Type' as well.

Comment: @lukaA, I figured this out, it will be `dt <- data.table(df, key=c("Date",'Type'))
dt <- unique(dt, by="Col1")
(dt <- dt[, list(Count=.N), by=c('Date','Type')][, Count:=cumsum(Count), by=c('Type')])`

Answer (score 0):

With ddply and duplicated, you just have to do

```
df <- ddply(data, .(Date, Col1), nrow)
df2 <- ddply(df[!duplicated(df$Col1),], .(Date), nrow)
ddply(df2, .(Date, V1), nrow)
```

ie you first count for all couples Date, Col1, then you remove the duplicated columns. You finally count the colums.

Your data must be sorted before.