# How to read file with irregular space separated value using fread()?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm learning to use `data.table`. Here is some [sample text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416918/data-table-or-dplyr-data-manipulation) I'd like to read into a `data.table`:

```
Date           Col1       Col2
2014-01-01     123        12
2014-01-01     123        21
2014-01-01     124        32
2014-01-01     125        32
2014-01-02     123        34
2014-01-02     126        24
2014-01-02     127        23
2014-01-03     521        21
2014-01-03     123        13
2014-01-03     126        15
```

`read.table` works fine here:

```
df <- read.table("dat", header=T)
```

When I try to use `fread()` from `data.table` package, I got the error:

```
DT <- fread("dat",header=T)
Error in fread("dat", header = T) : 
  Not positioned correctly after testing format of header row. ch=' '
```

I also tried to set `sep`:

```
DT <- fread("dat",header=T, sep="\t")
```

However, the structure is not right: 
It's only 1 variable `$Date` (it should be 3).

```
str(DT)
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Date           Col1       Col2: chr  "2014-01-01     123        12" "2014-01-01     123        21" "2014-01-01     124
```

How to use `fread()` here?

Comment: this answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229109/r-data-table-fread-command-how-to-read-large-files-with-irregular-separators

Comment: @bjoseph Thanks! Yes, `sed` works. Since `read.table` can handle the data perfectly, I suppose `fread` should handle it as well. If the data set is very large, the `sed` approach may also take some time. Maybe `fread` is a better choice if we could get it working.

Comment: agreed. there are some  github issues about this https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32620452/559784), this is now handled automatically by `fread` (see `README` for more):

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.5+
fread("~/Downloads/tmp.txt")
#           Date Col1 Col2
#  1: 2014-01-01  123   12
#  2: 2014-01-01  123   21
#  3: 2014-01-01  124   32
#  4: 2014-01-01  125   32
#  5: 2014-01-02  123   34
#  6: 2014-01-02  126   24
#  7: 2014-01-02  127   23
#  8: 2014-01-03  521   21
#  9: 2014-01-03  123   13
# 10: 2014-01-03  126   15
```

Either update to latest devel version or wait until v1.9.6 hits CRAN.

Comment: I updated to the latest dev-version and it works like a charm. Thank you!