# How to read tab separated file into data.table using fread?

Tags: r, data.table

Sample data (`emp.data`)

```
Beth  4.00  0
Dan   3.75  0
Kathy 4.00  10
Mark  5.00  20
Mary  5.50  22
Susie 4.25  18
```

I can read it into a `data.frame` using `read.table`, then convert it to `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- read.table("emp.data", col.names = c("Name", "PayRate", "HoursWorked"))
DT <- as.data.table(df, key = HoursWorked)
```

Calculate the pay (filter out zero hours):

```
DT[HoursWorked > 0, .(Name, Pay = PayRate * HoursWorked),]

    Name   Pay
1: Kathy  40.0
2:  Mark 100.0
3:  Mary 121.0
4: Susie  76.5
```

That works fine; however, I consider there's an extra step in converting. Since there's `fread()` in `data.table`, why not use it directly?

```
readDT <- fread("emp.data", header=FALSE, sep="\t")

               V1
1:  Beth  4.00  0
2:  Dan   3.75  0
3: Kathy 4.00  10
4: Mark  5.00  20
5: Mary  5.50  22
6: Susie 4.25  18

 str(readDT)
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: chr  "Beth  4.00  0" "Dan   3.75  0" "Kathy 4.00  10" "Mark  5.00  20" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

The data is recognized as one column; obviously this doesn't work.

**Question**

How to read this data using `fread()` properly? (If possible, set the column names as well.)

Comment: Try not to specify the `sep` and leave it "auto" (let `fread` decide). In other words just do `fread("emp.data", header=FALSE)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you. I got this error: `> readDT <- fread("emp.data", header=FALSE)
Error in fread("emp.data", header = FALSE) : 
  Not positioned correctly after testing format of header row. ch=' '`

Comment: It's hard to tell, can you provide a `dput` of your data set? Maybe also trying without specifying `header`

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload a small example data in dropbox or so?

Comment: @akrun Example data is at the very beginning of the question.

Comment: @Nick I had seen that, but I don't know whether that example have all the spaces in the correct way as the formatting here might be different than in your original dataset

Comment: @akrun I just copy the content and paste here. Did I break something in copy and paste? Will it help to get the file from gist: https://gist.github.com/nickleeh/07c1d0723aab557059a6#file-emp-data

Comment: I haven't tried with your example.  Let me try

Comment: I tried `fread("awk '{$1=$1}1' emp.data")` and it worked for me

Comment: @DavidArenburg I got the same error without specifying `header`. And the `dput` of the data: `dput(readDT)
structure(list(V1 = c("Beth  4.00  0", "Dan   3.75  0", "Kathy 4.00  10", 
"Mark  5.00  20", "Mary  5.50  22", "Susie 4.25  18")), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000320788>)`

Comment: @akrun May I ask what's the purpose of the `awk` command?

Comment: It removes the extra white spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed recently in the devel version, v1.9.5 (will be soon available on CRAN as v1.9.6):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
fread("~/Downloads/tmp.txt")
#       V1   V2 V3
# 1:  Beth 4.00  0
# 2:   Dan 3.75  0
# 3: Kathy 4.00 10
# 4:  Mark 5.00 20
# 5:  Mary 5.50 22
# 6: Susie 4.25 18
```

See `README.md` in the project page for more info. `fread` gained `strip.white` argument (amidst other functionalities / bug fixes) which is by default `TRUE`.

---

Update: it also has `col.names` argument now:

```
fread("~/Downloads/tmp.txt", col.names = c("Name", "PayRate", "HoursWorked"))
#     Name PayRate HoursWorked
# 1:  Beth    4.00           0
# 2:   Dan    3.75           0
# 3: Kathy    4.00          10
# 4:  Mark    5.00          20
# 5:  Mary    5.50          22
# 6: Susie    4.25          18
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for making `data.table` such a great tool. `col.names` is really handy too!

Comment: if for some reason you need to be explicit just do
`fread('~/Download/tmp.txt', sep = '\t')`

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk` to remove the white spaces and then reading with `fread` worked for me.

```
 DT <- fread("awk '{$1=$1}1' emp.data")
 DT 
 #      V1   V2 V3
 #1:  Beth 4.00  0
 #2:   Dan 3.75  0
 #3: Kathy 4.00 10
 #4:  Mark 5.00 20
 #5:  Mary 5.50 22
 #6: Susie 4.25 18

 str(DT)
 #Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
 #$ V1: chr  "Beth" "Dan" "Kathy" "Mark" ...
 #$ V2: num  4 3.75 4 5 5.5 4.25
 #$ V3: int  0 0 10 20 22 18
 # - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I was able to replicate the same problem with the OP's code

```
 fread("emp.data", header=FALSE, sep="\t")
 #               V1
 #1:  Beth  4.00  0
 #2:  Dan   3.75  0
 #3: Kathy 4.00  10
 #4: Mark  5.00  20
 #5: Mary  5.50  22
 #6: Susie 4.25  18
```

Comment: Thank you. I just read your answer. To my surprise that the `read.table` can handle this without problem. Maybe `read.table` is more smart.

Comment: @Nick `read.table/read.csv` should handle this.  I am not sure why `fread` has this type of problem.

Comment: I think your approach with `awk` is fine; however, I'm currently on Windows, and the version of `awk` on Windows doesn't work. So I tried to clean up with perl: `perl -pe 's/ {1,}/,/g' emp.data > emp.data.clean.perl`, then read it with `fread`. I'll check your awk approach when I'm back to linux.

Comment: Wrapping my head around that awk command: So it leverages that an if isn't necessary for a then (defaults to true) and a then isn't necessary for an if (defaults to printing the whole line) and assigning a value to itself actually strips out leading and trailing spaces (still can't believe that one).

Comment: @ClaytonStanley  Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.